# How to install µIP library on an embedded device

Tags: embedded, tcp, micro-ip

I'm currently working with the µIP TCP/IP library, for use on an embedded system. My question is a very simple one: I have downloaded the source code for the library, but how do I install it on my device? I realize that I have to build the library and then link it to my C file in which I am working with. Basically, I'm trying to build this library on a FOX G20 V embedded board (with *no* OS) with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor. Are there any helpful tips/links that might allow me to build the library on device. And as a bonus, if anyone has an idea how to modify the library to be specific to that platform for ethernet communications would be very helpful.

Comment: The answer will depend on your target platform, it's OS (if any), and how you have built the library. More detail required.

Comment: @Clifford THe platform is a FOX board with an ARM processor. I'm not quite sure what you mean by how I've built the library but it's a µIP version 0.9.

Comment: "ARM" does not narrow it down much, neither does "FOX board" of which there is more than one.  A part number or link would be helpful, but more importantly do you have an OS on it?  You should ideally answer by editing and improving the question rather than adding information in the comments.

Comment: Why are you not using [v1.0](https://github.com/adamdunkels/uip/tags)?  I took a quick look, it appears to be extensively documented; I'd start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library appears to have been subsumed into the [Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/) OS, but is available also as a stand-alone library. You might also consider [lwIP](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/) originally from the same author but supported as an open-source project in active development in it's own right.

In essence the library is not "installed" as such, but simply compiled and linked to your application code. Assuming that your target has no OS or a simple RTOS kernel, and that you are therefore using a hosted cross-development tool-chain, you would typically build the library (any library - this is not specific µIP) from the source as a [static-link library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library), then link that to your application code to create a monolithic application image, which is then loaded to your target's ROM.  It is also possible to compile and link the source to your application directly as you would any other source code without creating an intermediate static library - but this will extend your application build time, which may become and issue on a large project during development. However in this case µIP (having looked at the documentation) has a number of *compile-time* configuration options, that will be fixed if you build a static library; so if you envisage these things changing often, including the source code directly in your application project may be simpler.

You will no doubt also have to write, compile and link the platform specific device driver to allow the library to work on your hardware.  I have taken a look at the library documentation, and a device driver interface is defined.

It seems that you might need to familiarise yourself with the embedded development process more generally before you worry about integrating a third-party library.

Comment: 'Do I just do a "scp" and copy it on the device?' - if only.. :)

Comment: @MartinJames : Indeed, it seems John has not yet engaged in the embedded development process at all yet to be asking such an apparently naive question.

Comment: Thank you very much Clifford for your detailed reply. I understand that I'd have to write and compile the platform specific device driver to allow the library to work on the hardware, but it's at that point that I'm also having difficulties. I'm working with a certain processor (ARM AT91SAM9G20) and I've looked up in the documentation with regards to the register addresses that are used for Ethernet connections (that is what I'd have to add right?). But I'm not sure how to add a c file for such an implementation, and also, where to add this c file in the µIP library source code.

Comment: Also, do you have any tutorials as to how to build and link the library to a target? (I'm very unfamilier with embedded development as you mentioned).

Comment: It does not matter where or how you add the driver code; it is the job of the linker to find and resolve inter-module links.

Comment: You still need to add details of your development toolchain, which would be helpful to answer further questions.

Comment: For driver development, you might get a head start using [Atmel's own AT91Lib](http://www.atmel.com/tools/AT91SAMSOFTWAREPACKAGE.aspx) library, or the software support package for Atmel's own AT91SAM9G20-EK board, which may be similar to yours (at the same link).  In fact the latter appears to have uIP specific example projects (the projects with names starting *basic-emac-uip-...* seem to be what you need).

Comment: Thank you so much for the links/explainations Clifford. I really appreciate your time. I will look through the links and come back to you if I need any further help.

Comment: @Clifford I am trying to compile the µIP library in order to link it to my application code. But as I'm compiling, using `gcc -Wall -c uip.c`(uip.c being the first of the c files to compile), I immediately get an error `unknown type name 'uip_tcp_appstate_t'`. What I'm trying to do is to compile the c files in the uip folder, in order to create a .a file of the library and eventually link it to my application.